# Look and Feel não é atualizado em todos os subcomponentes

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

Estou enfrentando um problema com o look and feel que achei um pouco estranho, quando executo o projeto pela IDE todos os componentes são renderizados de acordo com o skin que eu selecionei, mas quando gero o JAR, alguns componentes não são renderizados com o tema que eu escolhi.

Tanto o JAR quanto pela IDE são iniciados através do código abaixo:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException 
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceBusinessBlackSteelLookAndFeel());

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Principal.main(args);
            }
        });
     }
}
```

Alguém já passou por algo semelhante, o programa funciona perfeitamente sem nenhum erro.

Segue aqui o link da documentação da biblioteca [Substance](http://insubstantial.github.io/insubstantial/substance/learn.html) que estou utilizando.

Versão do java CMD:

```
>java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
```

Na IDE é a mesma:
[image: JAVA IDE]

Comment: É possível que tenha duas versões de Java instaladas na seu pc. Por exemplo, rodando através de uma IDE ele usa um, e dando dois cliques no jar ele roda outra, e isso pode causar algumas diferenças sutis. Qual IDE está usando? Poderia dizer qual JRE ele usa? Tente rodar o jar pelo cmd usando o comando `java -jar arquivo.jar`. No cmd você pode verificar a versão do JRE fazendo `java -version`. Verifique se é a mesma que a IDE usa. Se não conseguir resolver seu problema tente gerar um exemplo (MCVE)[pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve] e se possível poste imagens.

Comment: Estou utilizando apenas uma versão do java, estou usando o Eclipse.

Comment: Fiz o teste em outras maquinas e com o Java 7 e também fica igual. To pensando que possa ser diferenças entre o JDK e JRE.

Comment: Não percebo porque estás a chamar outra função static main passando lhe o argumento args. Quando creias o JFrame com todos os componentes e quando tentas atualizar o L&F, deverias acercar a criação do objecto com um construto try/catch.
Se não mostras o codigo na outra função main, é dificil dizer e ajudar muito mais.

Comment: @claudsan escolha a sua resposta como a que responde a sua pergunta. Por aqui não usamos [Resolvido]

Comment: @gmsantos eu não posso marcar como resposta, vou editar o título, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade não foi um "problema" o que acontece é quando eu gero o jar executável pelo eclipse eu selecionava a opção **`Packaging required libraries into generate JAR`** com isso o Eclipse substitui a classe principal do jar por esta `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader`.

[image: Exportação Eclipse]

```
//A classe principal fica assim, e o skin MÃO funciona 100% alguns 
//componentes não aplicava o skin correto.
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Alterei para a opção: **`Extract required libraries into generate JAR`**
Não entendi o motivo mas funcionou pra mim. Porque de todo jeito ele passa pela minha classe App.